# iPad app should not install/usable in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I want to restrict some way for iPhones not to use the app which is intended for iPad only.

Are there ways not allowing user to install iPad apps on iPhones? Second case is even if its installed it should be usable in iPhones.

Let me know how to achieve this

Comment: If you release your app as iPad only (set this in the project settings) then it won't be available to iPhones.

Comment: i tried setting in info.plist as iPad only but it installed in iPhone.So will this be effective only when we release it to app store?

Comment: No need to edit info.plist directly; you must have done something wrong. Simply set "devices" to "iPad" in the "General->Deployment info" section of your project in Xcode and iPhone installation will not be possible.

Comment: Second case is even if its installed it should be usable in iPhones???

Comment: If you select "universal" as your target then it must work on iPhones. If you select iPad only then it won't be installable on iPhones so it can't be used.

Comment: Thanks...i did change only to iPad and its not installing in iPhone.Before posing question i tried the same,since there was already build installed in iPhone so it was my mistake.

Answer (score -1):

In the navigator (the left bar), select "show the projet navigator"(int the top bar, it's the icon completely to the left) . Then in Deployment info you're able to chose the Devices.

https://gyazo.com/47d1bb85b9e72a274ecba072ea676c4e